# jquery loading an image while async false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gif

I want to give a spinning gif image for the user to know something is happening while I am doing an ajax call with jquery. I have to use async:false because otherwise the code gets confused and we end up with a bad session variable. Here is what I have (that does not show the gif until after the call has frozen the screen.)

```
$('#status' + itemNum).html("<img width='14px' src='/style/images/spinner.gif'>");
if (foo == "bar") {
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url: "foobar.html",
   async:false,
   data: "val1=" + escape(newValue) + "&val2=" + fieldName + "&val3=" + newValue2
   })
} else {
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url: "foobar.html",
   data: "val1=" + escape(newValue) + "&val2=" + fieldName + "&val3=" + newValue3
   })
   document.getElementById('status' + itemNum).innerHTML = "SAVED";
}
$("#status" + itemNum).show();
setTimeout("fade_out('"+itemNum+"')", 1000);
}
```

In this case I only want the async when foo = bar. Can anyone let me know why the spinner.gif loads after the call. I am thinking that might be because the spinner isn't anywhere else and there is a delay in loading it, but still it doesn't show up when called multiple times (should be in cache by then), so I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the evil, painful world of SJAX.

Comment: Also, don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: What is wrong with passing a string to setTImeout?

Comment: It's possible the gif is taking longer to load than than the AJAX request.  Another way to do what you're trying to do is to pre-load (include on the page) the ajax loading gif, then clone/show in the status element.  use the `success: fn` callback in `$.ajax` to show the status and hide the loading gif.

Comment: when you pass a string, that string must be `eval()`ed (strike 1) and I think it is `eval()`ed in the global scope (putative strike 2.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible.
Since Javascript runs in the UI thread, `async: false` will freeze the browserm including all animation.

---

## **Do *not* use `async: false`!**

You need to fix your code to handle asynchronous requests.

Comment: :) I haven't found anyway to stop someone from continuously clicking the button though, any suggestion? I would like to disable it maybe even during the time the call is going on.

Comment: I added this as the answer because that is what I did, disable the button and use onsuccess to re-enable it

Answer (score 3):

`async: false` will lock the browser, resulting in all animations being paused until processing is allowed to continue. You can however get the graphic to at least show up before the ajax calls by placing the ajax calls inside of a `setTimeout` with a delay of 1ms or greater. It still will not animate though, even though it is an animated gif.

---

Of course, the above is just a bandaid, the better solution would be to not use `async: false`.

Comment: are there any options to show an animated gif while doing this ajax call and to make it go away afterwards