# simple way to do an ajax loading UI widget?

Tags: jquery

This is probably very standard, and I'm really surprised there isn't already a post on this. Important: I'm **not** using jQuery UI, thus looking for easiest way to achieve this:

```
function loadAjax(){
        $('body').append('<div id="status">loading...</div>');
        var out = '';
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url : "load.php", // i'm mimicking slow network by using sleep(3) in the php
            async   : false // yes, false! No clue why but my stuff won't work otherwise
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            out = $.parseJSON(response);
            $('#status').remove();
        })
}
```

Why does the `loading...` div not appear until *after* the ajax is finished? I'm trying to have it show up *before* the load, then disappear when the return object is sent.

Comment: I suggest that you fix the async part. Pretty pointless to do a synchronous `$.ajax` request. That will probably fix your other issue "automatically"

Comment: No it won't. I have a bunch of other code and setting the `async:true` is the only way I managed to make it all work okay.

Comment: It won't? http://jsfiddle.net/FGSxr/

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588994/jquery-loading-an-image-while-async-false

Comment: @Johan, I don't understand how adding a delay to the ajax request would be the same as having the actual request hang before it returns the data?

Comment: It's used to simulate your `sleep` on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the beforeSend callback

example:

```
$.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url : "load.php",
        beforeSend: function(){ $('body').append('<div id="status">loading...</div>'); }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Id do it like this...

Just set #status to `display:none;`

Then do this...

```
 $('#status').show();
 $.post('load.php', function(response){
   $('#status').hide();
   out = $.parseJSON(response);
 });
```