# Change .load() to $.ajax jQuery

Tags: ajax, function, jquery, load

I want to disable/prevent loading of the page until a JS call has been completed. I understand that the only way to do that is with `$.ajax` like so:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/acme/confirm_authentication.html",
 async: false,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data) {
    // loaded
 }
```

Currently, I’m loading a partial page with `.load()` function like so:

```
var linkUrl = $('.js-dialog--on-load').attr('dialog-href')  + ' #lga';
showDialogWindow(linkUrl);

function showDialogWindow(linkUrl) {
    $('.container').append($("<div>").load(linkUrl, function(){

    }).addClass('js-dialog'));
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SQDDD/1/

How can I translate this into an `$.ajax` call?

Remember, the reason I’m using `.load()` is so that I can load only part of the website (`#lga`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asyc: false` is (most of the time) evil ;-)

You may try something like :

```
function showDialogWindow(linkUrl) {
    $.ajax({
     url: linkUrl,
     async: true,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
         $('.container').append($("<div>"+data+"</div>").addClass('js-dialog'));
     }
    });
}
```

Be aware that you lose the selector feature available in the load

Comment: @jbi Thanks. Why is the `async: false` evil?

Comment: @Alex because it will freeze your browser for a possibly loooong time and will provide a really bad user experience. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7588994/1236044

Comment: @jbi I see. Then there’s no point to use `$.ajax` over `.load()` right?

Comment: @Alex there are differences.see the "Script Execution" on the load documentation .load is an utility method for above .ajax for the general case. As soon as you want to have more control on the behavior, .ajax is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [**at this example**](http://jsbin.com/ekIdEYE/1/edit) :

I have this html :

```
...
<body>
  <a href=""> aaa</a>
  <p>bbb</p>

</body>
...
```

now getting the `p` element from ajax :

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'http://jsbin.com/oFUMOtO/3/quiet',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data)
        {
          alert($("<div>").html(data).find( "p" ).text()); //alerts bbb

        }
    });
```